Scala 3 Extend a type from a type parameter in macro
Consider the following (broken) code:
def makeClass[T: Type](using q: Quotes): Expr[T] = '{
  class MyTest extends T { def foo: Int = 4 }
  new MyTest 
}

This fails with the following error:

A class type includes classes and traits in a specific order. Defining a class, even an anonymous class,
requires specifying a linearization order for the traits it extends. For example, A & B is not a class type
because it doesn't specify which trait takes precedence, A or B. For more information about class types, please see the Scala Language Specification.
Class types also can't have refinements.

Is there any way (type contraint, implicit parameter, etc.) that I could provide evidence to the compiler that T is a class or trait, and can be extended?
I'm aware of Symbol.newClass which I think does what I want. But besides being less ergonomic than quoting, it is still experimental, and it seems that @experimental is infections, and everything up the chain that uses the macro has to be experimental if I use it.
I also want to add any parameters on the primary constructor of T, if any, to the defined class, and pass them through, and I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

I'm afraid q.reflect.* (and @experimental) is necessary - '{ ... } works nicely only if you have all classes already defined, or if you create a new subclass, it's an (anonymous) class of a known type. Since this macro specifies T at the callsite, compiler cannot know ahead of time what will be its members, whether it's instantiable etc, so I'd expect the macro to complain. With reflect module you can define whatever you want, because some checks that would be done during '{ ... } definition, would be postponed until actual expansion, and you can/should verify some things yourself.
